# Best way to pre-aggregate time-series data in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, rollup

I have a table of sent alerts as below:

```
id | user_id | sent_at
1  | 123     | 01/01/2020 12:09:39 
2  | 452     | 04/01/2020 02:39:50 
3  | 264     | 11/01/2020 05:09:39 
4  | 123     | 16/01/2020 11:09:39 
5  | 452     | 22/01/2020 16:09:39
```

Alerts are sparse and I've around 100 Million user_ids. This table has total ~500 Million entries (last 2 months).

I want to query alerts per user in last X hours/days/weeks/months for 10 million users_ids(saved in another table). I cannot use any external time-series database and it has to be done in postgres only.

I tried keeping hourly buckets for each user. But data is so sparse that I've too many rows (userIds*hours). For eg. Getting alerts count for 10 Million users in last 10 hours takes a long time from this table.

```
user_id | hour                | count
123     | 01/01/2020 12:00:00 | 2
123     | 01/01/2020 10:00:00 | 1
234     | 11/01/2020 12:00:00 | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are not many alerts per user, so an index on `(user_id)` should be sufficient.

However, you might as well put the time into it as well, so I would recommend `(user_id, sent_at)`.  This covers the `where` clause of your query.  Postgres will still need to look up the original data pages to check for changes to the data.

Comment: Gordon, thank you for the quick reply. I do have the index on the user_id. I'll try adding `sent_at` to it. Problem is I query this for 10 Million users at a time by making a join with another table which has those user_ids. Should I first aggregate the count and then join? Or first join and then aggregate?

Comment: @Heisenberg . . . I think you should ask another question and be clear about the query you want to optimize.  What you have in the comment is not clearly in the question (you do allude to 10 million rows, but it is quite unclear what is happening).  That said, joining two such tables probably should not take an hour.

Comment: I've changed the question description. Maybe now it makes more sense.